# Template Tag Does Not Work in Page Template

Tags: page-template, template-tags

I've created a page template and used this code to call a post which contains a shortcode:

```
$post_id = 129;
if( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' ) {
    the_content();
}
```

The problem is that this code works fine in the index.php but not in my page template. Why is that?

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your post is not displaying properly is because functions such as [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), [`the_permalink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink), and [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) ( called [Template Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) ) can only be used whenever inside ["The Loop"](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) or whenever set up properly. There are two options to display your content properly:

**Functions: [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/), [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) and [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)**

First you would need to get the WP_Post Object and pass it into the `setup_postdata()` function so that WordPress can setup the template tags to pull in the correct content. Finally, we would need to reset the `global $post` object by calling `wp_reset_postdata()`.

```
global $post;               //  Get the current WP_Post object.

$post = get_post( 129 );    // Get our Post Object.
setup_postdata( $post );    // Setup our template tags.

if( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
    the_content();
}

wp_rest_postdata();         // Reset the global WP_Post object.
```

**Tad Easier using `apply_filters()`**

This is a little more straight-forward and doesn't require so much code which is nice. You won't have access to Template Tags like you would in the above example but if you're just displaying the post content and processing their shortcodes you won't need Template Tags.

```
$post_id = 129;

if( 'publish' == get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    $post_content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id );
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post_content );
}
```

The above grabs the content from the database then runs it through a WordPress filter which processes `the_content()` hook to give us our desired output, shortcodes processed and all.

Comment: Thanx sir, i'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_post()` function to get the post content by post id.

```
$post_id = 129;
if( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' ) {

    $post_content = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post_content->post_content;
    echo apply_filters('the_content',$content);
}
```

Comment: Do note though, this will not process any shortcodes but just display them in plain text.